# How to handle 500 errors

Tags: javascript, jsonp, mootools

The MooTools Request.JSONP method only has onRequest, onTimeout and onSuccess events to handle results.

I am attempting to call a web API using JSONP, but when there is an error at the service end, our developers return a 500 with valid JSON describing the error.

Is there a way using MooTools Request.JSONP to catch 500 errors? (Request.JSON is not an option in our specific case).

Is the only solution to always return a 200 for JSONP?

I am using More version 1.4.0.1

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Request.JSONP` is just a remote script injection. it then evals/serialises the response. it does not actually rely on XHR and as such, it gives you no way to interpret the HTTP response codes.

If you want to do this, you need to use normal `Request.JSON` AND enable CORS to allow external domains.

otherwise, nothing you can do:

https://github.com/mootools/mootools-more/blob/master/Source/Request/Request.JSONP.js#L85-L104

you can probably subclass this and add different logic in the `success` method to fire errors etc when the response if of a particular type, which you have to do on your own w/o the aid of serverside semantics. good luck

Comment: This is exactly as I thought - I was mostly being lazy hoping for a super clever way of detecting if the script tag load fails.

As an aside, we do have full CORS setup on server and normally use JSON x-site with no worries, however, We have hit some walls with IE7 and IE8 (which we have to support - but that's another story!)

Our solution is to have the service always return 200 if the callback prop is set (JSONP), and always include an error node in the resulting JSON if there is a problem. This works fine all the way back to IE6 *shudders*

Thanks.